# Python Script freezes at smptlib.SMTP(server) when running on CentOS server

Tags: python, centos, smtp

I've read a bunch of different questions on the same problem and tried multiple things. For reference, here's the code that I'm trying to run:

```
user = "enbee"
to = "ncbentley4@gmail.com"
subject = "Test"
message = "Test email"
email = user + "@leadshelperpro.com"
smtpserver = "mail.leadshelperpro.com"
header = 'From: %s\n' % email
header += 'To: %s\n' % to
header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
m = header + message
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver, 465, None, 30)
server.starttls()
server.login(user, 'password redacted')
server.sendmail(email, to, m)
server.quit()
```

I have verified that the smtpserver and the port are correct.
This script works when I run it from my local computer so it's not a firewall blocking connection. I've also used telnet to connect to the server and it works correctly.

I have tried using `server.ehlo()` both before and after `server.starttls()` (as well as before AND after at the same time).

Nothing I've tried up until this point has worked and I've been on the horn with support for the hosting service I'm using. They've changed some configurations of SMTP but nothing has worked. I'm still convinced it's an outbound connection being blocked but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support from my hosting company helped to show that port 465 only works for SSL connections. Changing the port to 587 and keeping the `server.starttls()` line fixed the problem.